# Is there any concrete risk involved in using the same password for root, kde wallets and key rings?

Tags: security

To make it easier I decided to use the same password for root (su(do)), kde wallet (KDE desktop) and keyring(s).

No one has access to this password in "real world" (given that the computer is accessed **only** by me, in a safe place). I also have Apache2 running but it's bounded to a specific directory and domain and it's the latest version.

My question is: besides me showing my password to anyone, is there any risk (e.g. potential exploit) someone (or even the programs which asked me to set kde wallet password and keyrings) or something can take advantage of this configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **always** a potential risks. One of them is that your machine is networked (but an [airgap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gap_malware) would not reliably solve that)

Others include but are not limited to:

- catching a [keylogger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging)  (hardware or software)
- keytrokes being recorded by more or less sophisticated means ([Van-Eck-Phreaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Eck_phreaking) or others)
- and, of course, don't forget that someone convince your to tell the password: https://xkcd.com/538/

### Conclusion

So, yes, there is always a concrete risk. I think you're question was more about the *probability with which those risks occur*.
But alas, answers to this question would be primarily opinion-based...

Comment: However, my question was: using the **same** password for different "system things".. does it (further) decrease security?
Also, is it really possible to have a keylogger in my system which runs in non-root mode (as I'd not insert the root password if a keylogger asked for it...)?

Comment: And the answer was: Yes, re-using a password is a bad idea. One more thing: You have a wrong idea of what a keylogger is: If it's a software keylogger, you do not even recognize that you caught one...